# Clean up all remote branches in git

Tags: git, bash, github

I'm trying to write a little bash script that will remove all branches in a repo locally and remotely except for 4 individual ones. What's the best way to do this?

Ones I'm trying to keep: `master, develop, stage, demo`

All the tutorials I see are mostly for any branch that's been merged and most of the time it's just local.

Comment: `git branch | grep -v "master\|develop\|stage\|demo" | xargs git branch -D`

Comment: What about remote branches? This only lists the branches I have locally.

Comment: `git branch -a --merged remotes/origin/master | grep -v  "master\|develop\|stage\|demo" | grep "remotes/origin/" | cut -d "/" -f 3 | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Hackerman's guidance, I was able to get this:

`git branch -r | grep -v "master\|develop\|stage\|demo" | grep "origin/" | cut -d "/" -f 2 | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin`